# Reading a string from a selected text from any software in Windows/MacOS

Tags: java, text, background, selection, text-cursor

First thing is first.. I am kinda new to this all stackoverflow thing, so excuse me for my formatting.

You have all heard about punto-switcher, right?
If not, it's a piece of software that runs in background and activates only when it spots that you're typing in your preferred language but with a different keyboard layout, and instantly changes it.

My question is a lot easier.. I want my program to read the text that I will select with my cursor in any software (as long as it is selectable) (I will provide a photo for better understanding) using a key bind on my keyboard... For example '`' or Caps Lock key.

Example of a selected text in MS Word:

[image: Example of a selected text in MS Word]

Also here is a piece of code for your better understanding of my idea. (Written in java)

```
public string function_that_reads_a_selected_string_from_cursor(){
variable_type bind = caps_lock
String read_string
//algorithm code
return read_string;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
String input = null;
input = function_that_reads_a_selected_string_from_cursor();
}
```

Any ideas?

P.S. The program should read it ONLY when the bind key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Java is able to do this without resorting to OS native functions given that your program will not have the input focus whilst capturing the text selected. Therefore you need to resort to [JNI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) (Java Native Interface) or [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (Java Native Access) and the invoked shared library will be OS-dependent.

Using JNI, after writing your library in C/C++ to capture the text selected, your Java code would look like as below (note the `native` keyword):

```
public native String function_that_reads_a_selected_string_from_cursor(int key_code);

public static void main(String[] args){
  int bind = VK_CAPITAL; // OS-dependent.
  String input = null;
  input = function_that_reads_a_selected_string_from_cursor(bind);
}
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jni) is a tutorial on how to use JNI.

**Edit:**
With regards to how to capture the selected text, I'd try:

1. Set a hook on the `bind` key to get your function called when the key is pressed
2. Use the OS API to copy the selected text to the clipboard and then from there to your program.